# Excel add-in - about microsoft certification to let add-in work without security notification

Tags: excel, deployment, add-in

I've developped an Excel Add-in (.xlam) that will be deployed for our clients.
I'm looking for any action /procedure/claim I should do to Microsoft to make it Certified or validated to bypass any high macro security level notification or user action.

Most of our clients should have such high level parameter, and they will be frustrated or annoyed if they have to click on any manual "activation" to let the add-in work...

We've already got a valide certificate we use to sign .dll or .exe files for independant softwares we produce, but I can't make it work for .xlam file...

info: the .xlam file is already Excel 2007, 2010, 2013 and 2016 compatible.

Any help will really be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create xlsm file with a single button as installer file, which trigger Install().

Install () Then convert the installer file from xlsm to xlam and add into excel addin.

It will auto open when user open their excel, no longer need to activate macro

**** Make sure the installer file contain the all of your logic

```
Sub Install()

Dim macroWBD, tempWBD As Workbook
Dim sFile, newPath As String
Dim oAddin As AddIn

newPath = "C:\Excel AddOns\"
addOnFileName = "~~~~"

    Set macroWBD = ThisWorkbook

    On Error Resume Next
    AddIns(addOnFileName).Installed = False
    Kill Application.UserLibraryPath & addOnFileName & ".xlam"

    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Saves current workbook as an .xlam file
    sFile = Application.UserLibraryPath & addOnFileName & ".xlam"

    If MakeDir(newPath) <> True Then MsgBox "Unable to install !": Exit Sub
    sFile = newPath & addOnFileName & ".xlam"
    macroWBD.SaveAs sFile, 55


    macroWBD.IsAddin = True
    'Adds temporary workbook
    Set tempWBD = Workbooks.Add

    'Installs the addin
    Set oAddin = AddIns.Add(sFile, False)
    oAddin.Installed = True

    'Closes temporary workbook
    tempWBD.Close False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox ("Installation Successful" & vbNewLine & "Please Restart Excel.")

    macroWBD.Close False


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm doing nearly the same in fact...
Are you sure this really bypass any activation notification or any "make this editor trusted" action by user even if Excel macro security level is 2 or higher?

Comment: And as your original xlsm file contains some code you should also get prompted when opening this file...

Comment: @bendev so far i have done few add on with this method, user only need to activate macro for once when they install, once it installed, it open at startup just like Personal Macro file. Hope this can help.

Comment: Ok, but my original question is to deal with this first and one-time notification. My boss want the user not to have to deal with this (even only one time, even if I told him this is a little excessive request...)
So the only way to this should be to be already approved editor, and this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: in that case no choice